# Telegram login hash check is failed in python

Tags: python, telegram

I'm trying to implement Telegram login to my site (https://core.telegram.org/widgets/login), and got stuck with hash checking problem - they just do not match.

The same function worked before, but now it's not, probably after i switched to python 3.11 (maybe that's why it's not working)

Here is my check function (sha256 is from hashlib):

```
def check_hash(body):
    secret_key = sha256(os.environ.get("TG_TOKEN", "").encode()).digest()
    hash_string = body.pop("hash")
    data_string = [f"{key}={value}" for key, value in body.items()]
    data_string = "\n".join(sorted(data_string))
    return hmac.new(secret_key, data_string.encode(), sha256).hexdigest() == hash_string
```

I also tried to use ready-made solution from github, but it failed too.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```py
import hashlib
import hmac
import time

def check_telegram_authorization(auth_data, bot_token):
    check_hash = auth_data['hash']
    del auth_data['hash']
    
    data_check_arr = []
    for key, value in auth_data.items():
        data_check_arr.append(f"{key}={value}")
    
    data_check_arr.sort()
    data_check_string = "\n".join(data_check_arr)

    
    secret_key = hashlib.sha256(bot_token.encode()).digest()
    hash_value = hmac.new(secret_key, data_check_string.encode(), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
    
    
    if hash_value != check_hash:
        raise Exception('Data is NOT from Telegram')

    if (time.time() - auth_data['auth_date']) > 86400:
        raise Exception('Data is outdated')
    
    return auth_data
```

Example :

```py
auth_data = {
    "id": 1234567890,
    "first_name": "name",
    "username": "username",
    "photo_url": "url",
    "auth_date": 1697025819,
    "hash": "0ff27c3a4f8c04ea145f19adf511c4bb1c6d347f7e70e79a9d344e9444434507"
}

bot_token = "123456789:abcd..."

try:
    result = check_telegram_authorization(auth_data, bot_token)
    print("auth success!")
    print(result)
except Exception as e:
    print("Error in auth:")
    print(e)
```